# Unable to add authorisation in headers to a GET request using axios

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, get, aws-api-gateway, axios

Recently, I needed to access the API gateway in AWS using my localhost environment. I am using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to do a `GET` request on the `API gateway` in AWS. The `GET` request requires an `Authorization` header in its request.

I used the following piece of the code

```
axios({
method: 'GET',
url: ROOT_URL+'/users/me',
withCredentials: true,
headers: {'Authorization':idToken} });
```

I can see that my `Authorization` is not getting attached to my request headers. I am getting the following error

```
message:"Missing Authentication Token"
```

I have also enabled cors request for my `API Gateway` in `AWS`. I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong while constructing the `GET` request using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: "Missing Authentication Token" is also returned if you use a invalid path (for a 404). Are you sure you are using the right path?